# webpack builds html but doesn't display any javascript

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

So i'm mostly new to javascript and current i'm having a problem displaying the fruits of our labor.  We have a webpack build from our React/Redux and although it displays css it doesn't contain any of the JS we've written.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure i'm missing something simple but i would greatly appreciate any help.

Here is the html file produced:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Talent Identification Manager</title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle-0.0.1.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

So here is the webpack configuration:

```
'let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');
const publicPath = '/dist/build/';
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
module.exports = {
    //Content
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    // A SourceMap without column-mappings ignoring loaded Source Maps.
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        }),
        //simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles. This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename which changes every compilation. You can either let the plugin generate an HTML file for you, supply your own template using lodash templates or use your own loader.
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Talent Identification Manager'
        }),
        //Auto replacement of page when i save some file, even css
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
        filename: 'main.bundle-0.0.1.js',
        publicPath: "",
        sourceMapFilename: 'main.map',
    },

    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost',
        //Be possible go back pressing the "back" button at chrome
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: false,
        stats: 'minimal',
        publicPath: publicPath,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
        //hotmodulereplacementeplugin
        hot: true
    },
    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules(?!\/webpack-dev-server)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
                    plugins: ['syntax-decorators']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

Comment: edit your src in html for script

Comment: it should be relative path to js bundle from html file

Comment: So the issue with this is that the div with the root ID was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this should be like this

```
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
        filename: 'main.bundle-0.0.1.js',
    },
```

plus give relative path in html file